# WordPress Contact Form 7 Plugin - How to save input data into jquery cookie?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I wonder if there's a way that I can save the user input data from Contact Form 7 into a cookie, preferably the jquery cookie plugin.

By doing so, I can retrieve these values when I visiting some other pages in order to display/re-process these data.

Contact Form 7 contains quite a few files and I am a bit lost. Any ideas or suggestions how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the form data from CF7 plugin and save it to jQuery cookie.Here's what I have done. ( kind of a quick and dirty way )

**Open scripts.js under includes/js/ directory, and find following line of code**

`$(data.into).find('form').resetForm().clearForm()`

This resets the form so form values will be all empty.

**Add the custom code before the code mentioned above**

For example, if i'd like to save the `name` value after email is successfully sent -- We can do this

```
if(data.mailSent == 1)
{
    var name = $('input[name="your-name"]').val();
    $.cookie('mycookie_namevalue', name, { path: '/' });
}
```

`your-name` is the default value for `name` attribute, or change it to whatever the value specified in CF7 plugin settings.

Comment: Editing a file in the includes directory of WordPress is never an option.

Comment: Instead of that, you can use a plugin that I have just created just for this feature and for a "Fill with Facebook" feature here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-autosaver/